# odoo, show data from function (not model)

Tags: odoo, odoo-view

for odoo, everywhere  i see that uses data from models.
To me need go on some site -> take data -> show on odoo
*(not webpage)*
is it possible?
example see on image
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot show data without saving it in database first.

i think you can create your own view that show data from a function But all standard odoo views fetch data from database. You have to save data than show it